# Adding type argument to EnumSet always give me "Bound mismatch"

Tags: java, generics, enumset

I have this code below:

```
public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> set1, Set<E> set2) {
    Set<E> resultSet = new HashSet<>(set1);
    resultSet.addAll(set2);
    return resultSet;
}
```

I want to overload one method like below, and get bound mismatch:

```
 public static <E> Set<E> union(EnumSet<E extends Enum<E>> set1, EnumSet<E extends Enum<E>> set2){
    Set<E> resultSet = set1.clone();
    resultSet.addAll(set2);
    return resultSet;
}
```

And I change to below, and it doesn't work.

Why? And how can I do?

Comment: And the bounds to the variable declaration for `E`.

Comment: Boris the Spider, thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `EnumSet` is declared as following

```
public abstract class EnumSet<E extends Enum<E>> extends ... implements ... { ... }
```

Here you can see that the type variable `E` is constrained to being a subtype of `Enum<E>`. Hence, you must constrain the type variable of your static method in the same way:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> Set<E> union(EnumSet<E> set1, EnumSet<E> set2) {
    Set<E> resultSet = set1.clone();
    resultSet.addAll(set2);
    return resultSet;
}
```